# Have a Column of Dates as Characters, Just Want the Years

Tags: r, date

I have a column of characters of dates in the format of MM/DD/YYYY and I want to convert them so its YYYY.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: try  `format(as.Date(date,format="%m/%d/%Y)","%Y")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert the dates, you can use:

```
format(as.Date(dates,format="%m/%d/%Y)","%Y")
```

Or just remove the day and month:

```
gsub("[0-9]*/[0-9]*/","",dates)
```